# how to protect a folder from git pull changes on server

Tags: git, gitlab

I am in need for a solution like if some one take pull from git changed files will get updated but for a particular folder content should not be updated either file changes coming through git repository in a particular folder. Every time i take pull on server and client complain me that few files are getting updated which should not be updated on server.

Comment: Isn't that a case for using forks or branches?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood it correctly, but if your problem is that people push changes to files that should not be changed, create a [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file and encourage developers to use forks and branches.

Also use [protected branches](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html) for avoiding people to push directly to an specific branch.

Comment: I did that i have a protected branch where developer send there request to merge
but suppose abc folder is in git and i don't want to accept any changes from abc folder i have already added that folder in .gitignore like abc/* but still files changes from abc folder comes through git. How i can ignore that files changes from abc folder.

Comment: From https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format -> "If the pattern ends with a slash, it is removed for the purpose of the following description, but it would only find a match with a directory. In other words, foo/ will match a directory foo and paths underneath it"